# Calling a class method of an associated eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having trouble figuring out how to call a class function, in this case `File->saveFile()` through the parent class `Article`

```
class Article extends Model {
  public $table = 'pl_gen_article';

  public function background_image () {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Ubercms\File', 'fileable');
  }
}

class File extends Model {
  public $table = 'ubercms_file';

  public function saveFile (UploadedFile $file) {}
}


$articleId = \Route::input('id');
$article = Article::findOrFail($articleId);
$file = $request->file('image');

// ----------------------
// Attempts

// 1.
$article->background_image->saveFile($file)

// 2.
$image = new $article->background_image();
$image->saveFile($file);
```

How do I create a `File` model instance from `Article` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the Laravel Api Docs traced the response of `$article->background_image()` which as [MorphOne](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphOne.html) instance, where I can call `firstOrNew` which returns an `File` instance and I'm able to call `saveFile` afterwards.

```
$model = $article->background_image()->firstOrNew([]);
$model->saveFile($file);
```